# Trying to restore images via clonezilla

Tags: linux-networking, pxe-boot, drbl

I'm trying to restore an image to a computer on a local area network.

I setup `drbl` via the `drblsrv -i` and `drblpush -i` commands, and pretty much left all those options to default (except for number of clients to choose).

For one, the whole boot sequence stops after the target client receives an IP, the only thing that shows up is the MAC Address along with the client IP.

I'm getting pretty frustrated as the machine just sits there, and doesn't actually do anything from then on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find anything useful in your research? Might be worth adding anything you've found to the question.

Comment: Actually I did, it turns out when I configured my server, I didn't need to set it to run a full linux boot, since I'm only using my server to clone/save images to. Hopefully this will be my solution as well.

Comment: It's been awhile but after digging around, I've found that my tftpd-hpa has an issues:

The client that receives the request acknowledges the tftpd request but then the server doesn't respond after a RRQ is issued by the client